# C++ Templates for inputting values

Tags: c++, templates

I started generic types in C++ recently. I was exploring it since, till I hit a wall here. Can I know where the problem is

```
template <typename T>
void testFun(T val) {
    cout << "the val is :" << val <<endl;
    return;
}

template <typename T>
T returnFun() {
    T val;
    cout << "Enter any value :";
    cin >> val;
    cout << endl;
    return val;
}

int main() {

    testFun(returnFun());
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'returnFun()'
     testFun(returnFun());
                   ^
```

Comment: How would you know what type `returnFun` will return? Thus, how'd the compiler know what type to pass to `testFun`?

Comment: `testFun(returnFun<int>());` maybe?

Comment: That is the whole point of using templates right? Runtime determination of types?

Comment: @AshwinPrasad ... no? Nothing about templates happens at runtime.

Comment: @AshwinPrasad, it's the exact opposite. Everything about templates must be known at compile time.

Comment: **compile time** determination (or rather *deduction*) of types.